# What do "Update Web/Service References" and "Update to latest version" do in VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2005, refresh

Presumably they do something different.

I still seem to have to remove and re-add references on occasion, and would like to be clear on what these things specifically do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, tiny breakthrough:

"Update Folder to latest version" relates to version control, not the webservice itself.

Therefore this was a quite silly question. Never-the-less, it seems I sometimes have to remove and re-add, because updating seems to not do the trick. Ho-hum.